# Azure data factory copy activity csv to cosmosdb fails

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

**Azure Data factory Copy Activity**

**Source**: csv file
**Sink**: cosmos db
**Operation**: upsert

Copy activity fails with code '2200', some issue with id field, It was working find before few weeks

My csv file has a number column that I am using as id for cosmos documents, so i can update existing ones

**Error details**

```
{
'errorCode': '2200',
'message': 'ErrorCode=UserErrorDocumentDBWriteError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Documents failed to import due to invalid documents which violate some of Cosmos DB constraints: 1) Document size shouldn't exceeds 2MB; 2) Document's 'id' property must be string if any, and must not include the following charaters: '/', '\\\\', '?', '#'; 3) Document's 'ttl' property must not be non-digital type if any.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDbManagement,'',
'failureType': 'UserError',
'target': 'Copy_ToCosmosDB',
'details': []
}
```

Comment: Hi, does my answer answered your question?If so,can you mark it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you upsert items in cosmos db,don't change your Partition key.Because the Partition key in cosmos db can't be changed.More Detail refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview).

For example:
My container's Partition key is `/name`,here is an item like this:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "no": 2,
    "name": "Monica",
    "createTime": "2020-06-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    
}
```

My csv file is something like this(update Monica to Monican):

```
id,no,name,createTime
2,2,Monican,2020-06-22T00:00:00.000Z
```

When I run the pipeline,I will get the same error with you.